# html how to fix a div to a page

Tags: html

I have something like this:

[image]

My css is:

```
td{
 font-size: medium;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #271D01;
 text-align: justify;
 line-height: 1.3em;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-variant: small-caps;
 min-width: 100px;

}
```

And my gsp:

```
...
        <g:each var="it3" in="${program[it2.id]}">
                              <td id="c1">
                                <div id="c1_div"><u><g:formatDate format="HH:mm" date="${it3.prog_start}"/> - <g:formatDate format="HH:mm" date="${it3.prog_end}"/></u></div>
                                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                                <div>${it3.prog_title}</div>

                              </td>
        </g:each>
...
```

How can i fix the hour-range in the div, so that no matter what size 'it3.prog_title' takes, the hour will display always in the same position, and also the title starting in same position. I'm expecting to do this via-css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to set `vertical-align: top` on your `TD`'s, and then just setup classes for your `div`'s to have a `margin-top` or `top` style to get the spacing you want between `div`'s.  This would also get rid of your spacer div and use CSS to position it how you want.  And while I'm at it, removed the `<u>` tag as well and replaced it with CSS.

**CSS:**

```
td {
  font-size: medium;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #271D01;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  min-width: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.time {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.title {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

**GSP:**

```
...
        <g:each var="it3" in="${program[it2.id]}">
          <td id="c1">
            <div id="c1_div" class="time"><g:formatDate format="HH:mm" date="${it3.prog_start}"/> - <g:formatDate format="HH:mm" date="${it3.prog_end}"/></div>
            <div class="title">${it3.prog_title}</div>
          </td>
        </g:each>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `vertical-align` on the table cell?

```
td{
 font-size: medium;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #271D01;
 text-align: justify;
 line-height: 1.3em;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-variant: small-caps;
 min-width: 100px;
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the hour-range relatively positioned to the top of the `<td>`